# xcode and iPhone simulations show weird top grey bar behind views after navigation, how to remove them?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, viewcontroller

I am trying to update an old Storyboard and viewControllers. in Interface Builder, my viewControllers has the following grey bar that I do not know how and why they are appearing, they were not there previously:
[image]

These are also visible when I try to simulate my apps in the iPhone simulator as follow:

[image]

When I start my app, the views are stretched with a tiny view of this space as follow:
[image]

However, when I start navigating to other viewControllers the space is visible as shown in the previous screenshot.

Any idea of how to stretch my views all the way to cover these areas?

I am currently using swift. The navigation is being done using Storyboard Segue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the storyboard showing the way the screen will be presented, that grey bar represents the `view` that will be behind that view controller. This kind of presentation is called `modal` (page sheet or form sheet) the two have different effects on iPad

### Code Fix

To fix this, change the `modalPresentationStyle` to `overCurrentContext` on the view controller you're going to present. So in code do `viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext`

### Storyboard Fix

in storyboard select the segue (the line linking the two screens) and then on the far right menu select the item 3rd in from the right, you should see a section called presentation, change it to `Current Context`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, I do not want it to be shown. Do you know how to disable it and make my views stretched all the way?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of your question, just updated my answer